# Spree 3 authorize.net feedback

Tags: spree, authorize.net, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm running a rails 4.2.2 project with spree 3.0.3 and noticed that when a payment fails (in this case I'm in the CMS, logged in as an admin) I only get the "failed" label right next to the payment. I'd like to be able to somehow hijack whatever authorize.net sends as a feedback so I can show the right message to the admin user. Right now, there's no way that the admin can say why the transaction failed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using the log_entries table. It has the messages sent by authorize.net